# Como guardar estas filas en BD - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas estoy intentando guardar esto en base de datos, bien puede ser una sola fila o más, depende de las filas que tenga el pedido:

```
#parameters: array:19 [▼
      "_method" => "put"
      "_token" => "token"
      "created" => "2020-10-29"
      "estadoPedido" => "0"
      "numeroFactura" => "34234232P"
      "direccion" => "9"
      "eProducto" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "41"
        1 => "42"
        2 => "30"
      ]
      "eTipo" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "49"
        1 => null
        2 => "18"
      ]
      "ePrecioUnid" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "30.00"
        1 => "15.00"
        2 => "10"
      ]
      "cntComprada" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "2"
        1 => "1"
        2 => "1"
      ]
      "eSubTotal" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "60.00"
        1 => "15.00"
        2 => "10"
      ]
      "idCliente" => "16"
      "nombreCliente" => "Nombre cliente"
      "dniCliente" => "472097523"
      "ticketCliente" => "202010041"
      "entregaCliente" => "9"
      "metodoCliente" => "transferencia"
      "smsCliente" => "Solo estoy en casa a partir de las 18:00"
      "envio" => "0.00"
    ]
```

Si no me equivoco seria hacer un foreach:

```
foreach($request as $item){
   $actPedido = Order::where('ticket', $id);
   $actPedido->producto = $item->name;
   ............
}
```

Es esto correcto? para que meta tantas filas como haga falta??

Si es correcto eso, tengo una pregunta, por ejemplo en `eProducto` traigo las id de los productos, entonces al guardarlos quiero hacer una query para guardar el nombre del producto.

```
$actPedido = Order::where('ticket', $id);
$actPedido->id_cliente = $request->idCliente;
$actPedido->cliente = $request->nombreCliente;
$actPedido->dni = $request->dniCliente;
$actPedido->idProducto = $request->eProducto;
           
$nameProduct = Product::where('id', $request->eProducto)->select('name')->get();

   foreach($nameProduct as $item){
      $actPedido->producto = $item->name;
   }
           
dd($actPedido);
```

Pero haciendo un `dd($actPedido)`  solo me trae el primer nombre. Es posible esto que estoy haciendo?

**EDITO:** Creo que tengo que convertir cada fila en un array pero no se como, es decir venga una fila por cada producto :S

Comment: `Product::where('id', $request->eProducto)` debería ser `whereIn()` ya que `$request->eProducto` es un array

Comment: Hola @L.Flor supongo que tendrás razón, pero no es lo que busco necesito pedido por fila, y tal como me viene no me sirve

Comment: Muestra tus tablas Order y actPedido, imagino que se relacionan, verdad?